# Bootstrap causing issues with my CSS

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

So I've looked at the other questions on here about Bootstrap overriding original CSS files but none helped fix my problem.  I put my CSS file last and no luck.
I have a hamburger in the top right corner and it becomes a black square, it works but when you click on it the slide menu goes behind my grid instead of in front of it. Also my Google fonts and sizing of text is not working.
My links as they are now.  My script file is at the bottom of the body.

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cabin:400,700|Arvo:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="AOS-Gallery.css">
```

https://jsfiddle.net/vrrfd1gx/4/

Below in Aziz's answer he help fix the issue with menu showing up behind the grid but claimed Bootstrap wasn't overriding my CSS.  If I go to the inspector to view my page I can see it is.  As a result the demo Aziz supplies does indeed work but the font is from BS not the one I put in and the font size is wrong too.  Also all my other pages for this website design without BS didn't need the added margin for the inner divs as Aziz suggests, which again makes me thing BS is affecting my CSS.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Welcome to SO, please provide the relevant HTML and CSS codes, ideally a jsFiddle demo so that we could help you identify the problem more clearly, it sounds like a specificity issue

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/vrrfd1gx/

Comment: Please narrow down (provide a [mcve] of) your problem.

Comment: remove the <script> tag from javascript section in your fiddle, set bootstrap css links in html head, and add jquery js and bootstrap js links and check again

Comment: done. but with the small screen on fiddle you don't see my issue. Not sure it's going to help.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is a problem with bootstrap, the inner divs simply have no gaps between them, you can space them out using margins:

```
.button div {
    height: 10%;
    margin-bottom: 10%;
    background: #000;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: .5s;
}
```

Also, if you want an element to be positioned from the RIGHT side of the viewport, use `right: 50px` instead of `left: 1000px` to ensure consistency across different screen sizes

```
.button {
    position: absolute;
    top: 30px;
    right: 50px;
    width: 45px;
    height: 50px;
}
```

And lastly, your menu was showing behind the gallery, apply a higher z-index to make sure it's on top:

```
 .menu-in {
   -webkit-animation: menu-in .9s forwards ease;
   z-index:2;
 }
```

[Working jsFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/azizn/vrrfd1gx/6/)

Comment: Oddly enough those buttons worked on other pages without the margins. Now to figure out why the "em" isn't working on my Title div.  Thanks for all the help, I appreciate it.

Comment: Aziz, You say my issue isn't with Bootstrap.  All of my other pages for this site do not have Bootstrap and did not need the line: margin-bottom: 10%; in the .button div.
Also the demo you link to is working but Bootstrap is adjusting the font and size from what I have in my code.  Do you have any ideas?  Thanks!

Comment: Hmm, seems like the problem might be coming from bootstrap's `box-sizing` global property: `* {
    /* -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; */
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    /* box-sizing: border-box; */
}` why are you not using bootstrap for other pages tho?

Comment: I hadn't needed it until now plus it was doing what it is now.  I was attempting to go without it but clearly I want features that will benefit from it.  Is there a way to contain the box-sizing?